# Using more than one namespace for an XSL Document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following snippet of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{11EA62F5-543A-4483-B216-91E526AE2319}</MessageId>     
    <SourceEndpoint>SomeSource</SourceEndpoint>
    <DestinationEndpoint>SomeDestination</DestinationEndpoint>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
      <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
        <DocPurpose>Original</DocPurpose>
        <SenderId>Me</SenderId>
        <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <_DocumentHash>ddd70464452c64d5a35dba5ec50cc03a</_DocumentHash>              
          <Backorder>No</Backorder>
        </CustInvoiceJour>
      </SalesInvoice>
    </MessageInvoice>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

As you can see, this uses multiple namespaces so when I want to transform this using XSL, I'm not sure which namespace I should be using as I need to gather some information from the `Header` tag and the `SalesInvoice` tag.

Here is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xheader="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xheader"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <header>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/xheader:SourceEndpoint" /></name>
    </header>
    <body>
      <test><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/*/*/*/xheader:Backorder" /></test>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the transformed document, the `SourceEndpoint` is populated but the `Backorder` isn't, because it uses a different namespace. So how can I make it use the different namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just have to declare and use both namespaces in your xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xheader="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:xsales="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xheader xsales"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <header>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/xheader:SourceEndpoint" /></name>
    </header>
    <body>
      <test><xsl:value-of select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:Backorder" /></test>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to exclude both `xheader` and `xsales` from `exclude-result-prefixes`

Comment: Just include both - exclude-result-prefixes="xheader xsales".  I'll update the answer to do this.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was trying that but with a comma: `exclude-result-prefixes="xheader, xsales"`!